# How to quick convert a String array to Two-Dimensional char Array by java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, character

if I has a String array:

```
String[] strArr = {".87654321","2........","3........","4........","5........","6........","7........","8........","9........"}
```

I want to convert it to char[][]

My way is to add toCharArray() to each String,but it is too trouble:

```
char[][] charArr = {".87654321".toCharArray(),"2........".toCharArray(),
```

What is the quick way to convert it to char[][]?

Comment: Please specify *quick* - quick in sense of fast execution or "quick" in writing short code?

Comment: writing short code  @BinkanSalaryman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
char[][] convertToTwoDimArray(String[] strArr){
  char[][] ret = new char[strArr.length][];
  for(int i=0; i<strArr.length; i++){
    ret[i] = strArr[i].toCharArray();
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Simple, and best answer possible. I was just about to post that one.